# Responsively Positioning Elements Absolutely over Background

Tags: html, css, positioning, absolute, responsive

I have three elements that I want to keep in the same place as the image responsively shrinks.

```css
.main
{
 position: relative;
}

.container
{
 display: inline;
}

.point
{
 display: inline;
    position: absolute;
 max-width: 15%;
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding: 3px 7px 3px 5px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 background: #ff0000;
 border-radius(5px);
 box-shadow(1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}

.one
{
 top: 40%;
 left: 10%;
}

.two
{
 top: 50%;
 left: 40%;
}

.three
{
 top: 75%;
 left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="point one">1</div>
    <div class="point two">2</div>
    <div class="point three">3</div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/M5SHKCxKDgs/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Husky">
</div>
```

Comment: @DeepakYadav I rollbacked your edit as it in inappropriate. Edits such as those; that try to correct the question; are not welcome on SO as they change the actual question. If you have further issues or have question, please go ask about this on meta.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No issues bro. If you found it inappropriate. there might be a reason for that. it's ok. Thanks for doing so :)

Comment: @DeepakYadav great! looking in your history I realized this is indeed not a habit of yours. cheers

Comment: @felix thanx bud ..  will drink to that today :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want it also to scale as the image scales down responsively, so this achieves that effect.

```css
.wrapper {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .wrapper img { max-width: 100%; }
    
    .point
    {
      position: absolute;
     max-width: 15%;
     margin-right: 10px;
     padding: 3px 7px 3px 5px;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #fff;
     background: #ff0000;
     border-radius(5px);
     box-shadow(1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
    }
    
    .one
    {
     top: 40%;
     left: 10%;
    }
    
    .two
    {
     top: 50%;
     left: 40%;
    }
    
    .three
    {
     top: 75%;
     left: 20%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/M5SHKCxKDgs/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Husky">
    <span class="point one">1</span>
    <span class="point two">2</span>
    <span class="point three">3</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I am using `inline-block` to automatically allow the `wrapper` element to "wrap" around the image no matter what size the image is. I also set `max-width: 100%` to turn the image into a responsive image (well, it just scales down when the window resizes). Since the points are all %-based, they stay in the right position as the image scales down.

✔ No requirement to have a fixed width and height image/wrapper, so it's responsive
✔ Less HTML required
✔ Works on pretty much any browser besides unsupported old ones

This is a nice trick I've used to do things like "banners" across images and other techniques to position things over images for effects.

Comment: This is so weird! It works separately, but when I apply the fixes to my existing code, it still does not work. Oh well, guess I need to do some more tinkering. A winner is you!

Comment: Check Dev Tools in browser and double check the "wrapper" element has a `position: relative` and `display: inline-block` as that is the key to making it work.

Answer (score 0):

Make your container as **position relative** and set a height and width on it since the child of your **container** is absolute. Also make your **image** absolute positop and top 0. See snippet.

```css
.container
{
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
 position: relative;
}
.main img{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;}

.point
{
 display: inline;
    position: absolute;
 max-width: 15%;
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding: 3px 7px 3px 5px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 background: #ff0000;
 border-radius(5px);
 box-shadow(1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}

.one
{
 top: 40%;
 left: 10%;
}

.two
{
 top: 50%;
 left: 40%;
}

.three
{
 top: 75%;
 left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="point one">1</div>
    <div class="point two">2</div>
    <div class="point three">3</div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/M5SHKCxKDgs/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Husky">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set width and height for your `img` tag.

```css
.main
{
 position: relative;
}

.container
{
 display: inline;
}

.point
{
 display: inline;
    position: absolute;
 max-width: 15%;
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding: 3px 7px 3px 5px;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
 background: #ff0000;
 border-radius(5px);
 box-shadow(1px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
}

.one
{
 top: 40%;
 left: 10%;
}

.two
{
 top: 50%;
 left: 40%;
}

.three
{
 top: 75%;
 left: 20%;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="point one">1</div>
    <div class="point two">2</div>
    <div class="point three">3</div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/M5SHKCxKDgs/hqdefault.jpg" alt="Husky">
</div>
```